# mariaDB foreign key unformed - varchar not a signed/unsigned issue

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mariadb, foreign-key-relationship

MAC Sierra 10.12.2
mariaDB Vers 10.1.19
Construct statements are cut/paste from Querious Table Syntax window.

First table:

```
CREATE TABLE `USAStates` (
  `state_id` int(11) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `state_abbrev` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `electoral_votes` smallint(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `fed_reg` smallint(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `econ_anal_reg` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FRB_district` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`state_id`,`state_abbrev`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=52 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Second Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `FRBCommentary` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `state_abbrev` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `FRB_district_rem` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`state_abbrev`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=52 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Results of ALTER statement from command window; same results using Querious tools:

```
MariaDB [ESHOP]> 
    ALTER TABLE FRBCommentary
    ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (state_abbrev)
    REFERENCES USAStates (state_abbrev);
```

> ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `eshop`.`#sql-74b_41` (errno:
>   150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") MariaDB [ESHOP]>

Used to be very competent at MS Access...years later trying to learn the real thing.

Comment: Suggest you get rid of `id` and make `state_abbrev` the `PRIMARY KEY`, by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need an index on the referenced column.

```
ALTER TABLE USAStates ADD INDEX (state_abbrev);
```